# CSS styling for Google Translate plugin - Flag size customization

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to edit the size of the flag which is been added to our [Website](http://www.coachhire4u.com). I can see Add CSS styles box but not sure whether it will help me to change the flag size from rectangle to circle. I am new to wordpress and its really difficult to modify. Any one help me with this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make them looking round by adding border-radius to the flags' li-elements like this;

```
#flags li {
border-radius: 11 px;
}
```

However, there seems to be some settings that override the sizing, so you might have to tweak a bit, where exactly you can adjust the size before getting nice round flags.

It would help to see how the plugin/that part of the code is actually laid out there for you as an admin, so it could be pinpointed how exactly tweak it to make it look all nice and pretty.

Comment: I am using Google Language Translator Plugin Settings page where it has options like flag size, flag for english etc.. it also have a text box "Add CSS Styles".

Comment: Oh, my bad, it suppose to be `#flags a` instead of `#flags li`.

As you see, it doesn't present the flags completely round. I would suggest to settle with this, because otherwise you have to tweak the required settings everytime the plugin has an update. 

If you want to see that trouble, let me know, there is just so much space you can write on these comments and it's bit lenghty answer!

Comment: Okay, once you press "Save", does the piece of code you added show on the "Add CSS Styles"-section?